# How to add new file types to Makefile?

Tags: makefile, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to create a Makefile using GNU Make 4.0, but am running into an issue.  This is on an IBM i, version 7.2, in the QP2TERM PASE environment.  The file types are non-standard on this platform.  Every source file ends in ".mbr"; the source code type can be gleaned by the directory name containing that code.  So C code is in directory QCSRC, C headers are in directory H, and RPG code is in directory QRPGLESRC.  Source code gets compiled into modules, and modules get combined into programs.  To keep things simple, this test only tries to compile one source file into a module.

```
all: file1.module

file1.module: file1.mbr
    system "(compile instruction here...)"
```

The result of `make all` is `make: 1254-002 Cannot find a rule to create target file1.mbr from dependencies.`  So it seems that Make doesn't realize that *.mbr is a source file.  How do I tell it that anything ending in .mbr is a source file?  Even better, how do I tell it that anything ending in .mbr in directory QCSRC is C source, and anything ending in .mbr in directory QRPGLESRC is RPG source, so I can specify the relevant compile instructions?

I had some limited success defining .SUFFIXES, but the Make manual says that pattern rules should be used instead.  I tried this without success:

```
all: file1.module

%.module: qrpglesrc/%.mbr
    system "(compile instruction here...)"
```

But now the error given is `make: 1254-002 Cannot find a rule to create target file1.module from dependencies.`

Comment: The error message seems to recognize the name `file1.mbr`, but it can't find the file so it thinks it needs to create it — and doesn't know how to do that.  That's a different problem, I think.  Is the `file1.mbr` in the current directory or in a sub-directory?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you're right!  The current directory was set to the directory containing the makefile, not the actual code.  When I `cd` to the QRPGLESRC directory then Make works (for that one test).  If I cd to the parent directory containing all the source code directories, then it doesn't work.

I did use VPATH to specify the parent directory -- I thought that would take care of it but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Many issues with the question. Hard to tell what naming convention you're trying to use since you refer to both QSYS and IFS names, and they don't mix. Can you edit to include OS version (apparently at least i 6.1). Also, what "make" are you trying to use? QShell make? PASE make? GNU make? TMKMAKE? (Other?) Finally, can you edit to indicate your experience, both with make and with IBM i? There is much that might be written, but hard to tell how background info to include.

Answer (score 0):

If your `make` program is [POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) then you can use the `.SUFFIXES` special target and set up suitable [inference rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_06).

For example you could have something like (pseudo only)

```
.SUFFIXES: .suffix_used_to_create_mbr_files

.suffix_used_to_create_mbr_files:
    command-to-create-mbr-file
```